# Peak-current mode control, active clamp forward converter: magnetization vs. reflected current

Tags: dc-dc-converter, forward

I figured out the forward converter, and I'm currently reading [app-note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/app-notes/designing-activeclamp-forward-converters-using-peakcurrentmode-controllers.pdf) where state:

> The converter is a peak current-mode controller that controls the peak current as seen by the
> current-sense resistor, which is the sum of the reflected load current and magnetizing current. It
> is necessary that the magnitude of reflected load current is always more than the magnetizing
> current for stable converter operation and well regulated output. This condition is always
> satisfied, if the magnitude of reflected load current at the input minimum is more than the
> magnetizing current. Hence, **peak-to-peak primary magnetizing current is assumed to be half of
> the reflected load current** at minimum input voltage

Do I understand correctly that it is needed in order for the feedback to 'know' what is really occurring in the load?

If the answer is yes, then how will the forward converter work with a slight load?

Comment: It may be worthwhile to consider it is an *active clamp* type converter (I've updated the title to reflect this).

Comment: Your question is valid. If you are in CCM but light load, the magnetization current could be a significant portion of your measured current. For any OCP or similar, this does not matter as you are below the threshold anyway.